# dse solr suggester status 403 - Unknown command 'suggest'

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I've followed at least a dozen different examples, all of which look mostly the same. I'm using DSE 5.1 and SOLR and trying to play with the suggester. Here is my configuration (mostly vanilla from the examples):

```
  <searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
     <lst name="suggester">
       <str name="name">titleSuggester</str>
       <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
       <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
       <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">TextField</str>
       <str name="field">title</str>
       <str name="weightField">rating</str>
       <str name="payloadField">description</str>
     </lst>
  </searchComponent>
  <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="suggest">true</str>
      <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
       <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

When I try to run curl to access it on the local host, I get:

```
message Unknown command 'suggest' in request
   description Access to the specified resource has been forbidden
```

Here is the curl command:

```
curl --user myuser:mypass \
 "http://localhost:8983/solr/test.movies/suggest?suggest=true&suggest.dictionary=titleSuggester&suggest.q=Po"
```

Can't figure out for the life of me why my implementation doesn't work. Any ideas?

Here is the output of the comment to describe the config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<config>
  <luceneMatchVersion>LUCENE_6_0_1</luceneMatchVersion>
  <dseTypeMappingVersion>2</dseTypeMappingVersion>
  <directoryFactory class="solr.StandardDirectoryFactory" name="DirectoryFactory"/>
  <indexConfig>
    <ramBufferSizeMB>512</ramBufferSizeMB>
    <rt>false</rt>
  </indexConfi`enter code here`g>
  <jmx/>
  <updateHandler>
    <autoSoftCommit>
      <maxTime>10000</maxTime>
    </autoSoftCommit>
  </updateHandler>
  <query>
    <filterCache class="solr.SolrFilterCache" highWaterMarkMB="2048" lowWaterMarkMB="1024"/>
    <enableLazyFieldLoading>true</enableLazyFieldLoading>
    <useColdSearcher>true</useColdSearcher>
    <maxWarmingSearchers>16</maxWarmingSearchers>
  </query>
  <requestDispatcher>
    <requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="true" multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048000"/>
    <httpCaching never304="true"/>
  </requestDispatcher>
  <requestHandler class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true" name="search"/>
  <requestHandler class="com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.handler.component.CqlSearchHandler" name="solr_query"/>
  <requestHandler class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler" name="/update"/>
  <requestHandler class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler" name="/update/csv" startup="lazy"/>
  <requestHandler class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler" name="/update/json" startup="lazy"/>
  <requestHandler class="solr.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler" name="/analysis/field" startup="lazy"/>
  <requestHandler class="solr.DocumentAnalysisRequestHandler" name="/analysis/document" startup="lazy"/>
  <requestHandler class="solr.admin.AdminHandlers" name="/admin/"/>
  <requestHandler class="solr.PingRequestHandler" name="/admin/ping">
    <lst name="invariants">
      <str name="qt">search</str>
      <str name="q">solrpingquery</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">all</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
  <requestHandler class="solr.DumpRequestHandler" name="/debug/dump">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <str name="echoHandler">true</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
  <searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">titleSuggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">FSTLookupFactory</str>
      <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
      <str name="field">title</str>
      <str name="weightField">rating</str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">TextField</str>
      <str name="payloadField">description</str>
      <str name="buildOnStartup">true</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>
  <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="suggest">true</str>
      <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
</config>
```

Here is the output of the describe on the table:

```
CREATE TABLE test.movies (
    title text PRIMARY KEY,
    author text,
    description text,
    rating float,
    release_date timestamp,
    solr_query text
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX test_movies_solr_query_index ON test.movies (solr_query) USING 'com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.Cql3SolrSecondaryIndex';

describe active search index schema on test.movies;

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<schema name="autoSolrSchema" version="1.5">
  <types>
    <fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.StrField" name="StrField"/>
    <fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TrieDateField" name="TrieDateField"/>
    <fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TrieFloatField" name="TrieFloatField"/>
    <fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField" name="TextField">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
  </types>
  <fields>
    <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="title" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
    <field docValues="true" indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="release_date" stored="true" type="TrieDateField"/>
    <field docValues="true" indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="rating" stored="true" type="TrieFloatField"/>
    <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="author" stored="true" type="TextField"/>
    <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="description" stored="true" type="TextField"/>
  </fields>
  <uniqueKey>title</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

Comment: Have you reload config? You can look into this example: https://github.com/alexott/datastax-bootcamp-project/blob/master/cql/inventory.cql - it's in CQL that is more preferable as XML now

Comment: How do you upload this config? Can you run in the `cqlsh` following command; `describe active search index config on test.movies;` ?

Comment: dsetool -l <user> -p <passwd> create_core test.movies schema=test.movies.schema2 solrconfig=test.movies.config4 (I modified the quesiton above to contain the config describe output)

Comment: Can you also add output of `describe table test.movies;` and `describe active search index schema on test.movies;` ? I just checked my code, and suggester works without problems, although I'm using slightly different classes for lookup.

Comment: Added describe output to the original post. Yeah, the people at datastax could not figure it out either. I've tried a brand new cluster and get the same results - so it isn't the cluster, but some configuration (could be an O/S issue (e.g. firewall - which is disabled), or dse issue - not sure).

Comment: Can you check with changes that I pointed in answer?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce exactly this problem - when I'm using `FSTLookupFactory` implementation, DSE 5.1.11 throws NullPointerException.   But I made it working with `AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory` implementation, and following config:

```
  <searchComponent class="solr.SuggestComponent" name="suggest">
    <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">titleSuggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
      <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">TextField</str>
      <str name="field">title</str>
      <str name="weightField">rating</str>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
      <str name="exactMatchFirst">true</str>
      <str name="payloadField">description</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>
```

that was generated by following CQL (it's more preferable than use XML files):

```
CREATE SEARCH INDEX ON test.movies WITH OPTIONS { reindex : false };
ALTER SEARCH INDEX SCHEMA ON test.movies SET field[@name='title']@type='StrField';
ALTER SEARCH INDEX SCHEMA ON test.movies SET field[@name='description']@type='TextField';

// create suggestion component & corresponding request handler.
ALTER SEARCH INDEX CONFIG ON test.movies ADD searchComponent[@name='suggest',@class='solr.SuggestComponent'] 
WITH  $$ {"suggester":[{"name":"titleSuggester"}, {"lookupImpl":"AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory"}, {"dictionaryImpl":"DocumentDictionaryFactory"},
{"suggestAnalyzerFieldType":"TextField"}, {"field":"title"}, {"weightField":"rating"}, {"buildOnCommit":"true"}, {"exactMatchFirst":"true"}, {"payloadField": "description"}]} $$;
ALTER SEARCH INDEX CONFIG ON test.movies ADD requestHandler[@name='/suggest',@class='solr.SearchHandler'] 
WITH  $$ {"defaults":[{"suggest":"true"}, {"suggest.count":"10"}],"components":["suggest"]} $$;
RELOAD SEARCH INDEX ON test.movies;
```

and it works:

```
>curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/test.movies/suggest?suggest=true&suggest.dictionary=titleSuggester&suggest.q=best&wt=json'
{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":1},
   "suggest":{"titleSuggester":{"best":{"numFound":1,
   "suggestions":[{"term":"the <b>best</b> movie","weight":1,
      "payload":"super movie"}]}}}}
```

Comment: So I tried exactly what you had above, and it still fails to work. When I try the exact URL you have, it fails due to requiring authentication. So I add the http://user:pass@localhost/... and get the following message: {"responseHeader":{"status":403},"error":{"msg":"Unknown command 'suggest' in request","code":403}}

Comment: When I remove the &wt=json, I see the following, again: Access to the specified resource has been forbidden

Comment: does user has correct permissions to search indexes? Look here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/security/secSearchIndexPermissions.html Also look to this one: https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/srch/reqPermSolrAdminUi.html

Comment: There were no permissions on the search indices so I granted ALL PERMISSIONS on ALL INDICES to my user and re-tried, it failed. What I did find out is that what seems to be causing the issue is the "authorization_options" in the dse.yaml. When I un-comment that (which is what we use) I get the errors described above. When I comment out the authorization_options, it seems to work. So not sure why that's causing problems but I've tried all combinations of it uncommented and it fails for every one of them. It only works when commented out.

Comment: yeah, that's something with permissions I think... Maybe it makes sense to file a support ticket?